# Own spreadsheet web application server

Tags: web-apps, self-hosted, spreadsheet

I need to embed spreadsheets in my web application, something similar to Google Sheets.

I also need to store the data in my server (i.e. embedding Google Sheets and storing the sheet in Google's server is not what I'm looking for).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

## Vaadin

The [Vaadin framework](https://vaadin.com/framework) is a way to create interactive web-apps with the quality and style of desktop apps using pure Java on the server-side that are rendered automatically on the client-side using standard web technology transparently to the programmer.

Your Vaadin web app actually lives on the server though appears to the user in their web browser. The data lives on the server in Java, and can easily be saved as files on the server’s disk storage or the data can be sent to a database for storage.

The Vaadin framework is free-of-cost and open-source.

## Vaadin Grid

Among the many widgets included in the framework is [Vaadin Grid](https://vaadin.com/grid), for presenting and entering tabular data. Though not as sophisticated as a spreadsheet, it can serve the more rudimentary use-cases of a spreadsheet.

Free-of-cost, and open-source.

## Vaadin Table

The [Vaadin Table](https://vaadin.com/docs7/-/part7/framework/components/components-table.html) widget is the predecessor to Vaadin Grid. Still available even in Vaadin 8 through the Vaadin 7 compatibility layer. Has many features and behaves different than Grid, so it may be able to meet needs unmet by Grid.

Free-of-cost, and open-source.

## Vaadin Spreadsheet

The [Vaadin Spreadsheet](https://vaadin.com/spreadsheet) is a commercial add-on (plugin) for the Vaadin Framework to provide more sophisticated spreadsheet features along the line of Microsoft Excel and LibreOffice.

See the [live demos](http://demo.vaadin.com/spreadsheet/).

See the [video case-study](https://youtu.be/y_LrQ0QfjfE).

Comment: Vaadin seems to run its own Java server, how can I embed it in my application if I run a different server, such as Play, Jboss or .NET?

Comment: @ps0604 Indeed, currently Vaadin Spreadsheet runs only within the Java Framework (which I highly recommend) on a Java Servlet container server. However, the Vaadin company is a leader in the new movement for Web Components. They have released Vaadin Grid separately as a Polymer component. I don't know of their plans but it might be possible that Vaadin Spreadsheet goes the same way in the future.

Answer (score 2):

[ethercalc](https://ethercalc.net/) is available as a docker package you can self-host but you can also install it normally on GNU/Linux, FreeBSD, Mac OS X and Windows, using node.js. It runs with Redis, if available, or fall back on file-storage. And even better, it is a free software.

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion provides a Spreadsheet control [ejSpreadsheet](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/spreadsheet/) that can be used to host your own spreadsheet within a web application similar to Google Sheets. A .NET backend is required ([ASP.NET Core is also an option](http://aspnetcore.syncfusion.com/spreadsheet/default))

[image]

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense?refer=srecs40302) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.